# How to generate UPS SOAP envelope and soap security header ??

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, soap, ups

I am using `UPS Web API` in ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application. Also I contacted ups developer support team. But they replied as below:

> If you are using Web Services, be sure to include the SOAP envelope and the SOAP security header. Please do not remove the user ID/password and Access Key from the request file.
>
> You will need to debug your application to obtain the XML/Soap Envelope request and response files. Regrettably, due to the many possible programming languages and environments, we do not support client code directly and are unable to provide you with instructions on how to complete this process for your programming environment. "

So, How to generate the SOAP envelope and soap security header? Please help me if anyone faced the same issue???

Comment: More context would be really helpful - how do you create the XML now and what error message do you get back? If you're looking for an easier solution you could consider using Shippo (https://goshippo.com) and their C# client library (https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-csharp-client).

Answer (score 0):

[Download Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and install it on the machine sending the web service request. While you have it running, Fiddler will show you the request and response when you make the web service call, and you can choose the Text View tab in both the request (top right) and response (bottom right) panes in Fiddler to copy and paste the raw XML into text files.

[image: Fiddler running with request and response set to text view]